# Changing mvc form controller on submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, razor

I recently came upon this question as I have a solution I need to work on.

I have a controller which does some logic, with some method:

```
   public Controller1: MvcController
   {
     public ActionResult SomeLogic(Model model)
     {
       return view();
     }
     public ActionResult SomeLogic2(Model model)
     {
       return view();
     }
  }
```

And I have a second controller which does different logic:

```
   public Controller2: MvcController
   {
     public ActionResult SomeLogic(Model model)
     {
       return view();
     }
     public ActionResult SomeLogic2(Model model)
     {
       return view();
     }
  }
```

Both are working on the same view:

```
MyView.cshtml
```

The view contains a begin form that works on submit:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("SomeLogic", "Controller1", FormMethod.Post)
```

and 4 submit buttons:

```
<input type='submit' formaction='SomeLogic' value='submit' />
<input type='submit' formaction='SomeLogic2' value='submit2' />   
<input type='submit' formaction='SomeLogic' value='submit3' />
<input type='submit' formaction='SomeLogic2' value='submit4' />
```

I know I can control the action to which I am redirecting the submit using the:
`formaction` attribute.

I there a way to change the controller as well? meaning that:

```
<input type='submit' formaction='SomeLogic' value='submit3' />
<input type='submit' formaction='SomeLogic2' value='submit4' />
```

Will submit to `controller2` instead of `Controller1` which is defined in my begin form.

This will solve my debate whether to create a new controller or use the existing one, which is already full of complex logic.

Comment: `formaction="@Url.Action("SomeLogic", "yourControllerName")"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include controller name in the `formaction` attribute.

Note that your controller names are not valid, but assuming your have

```
public FirstController: Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SomeLogic(Model model)
    {
        return view();
    }
}
public SecondController: Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SomeLogic(Model model)
    {
        return view();
    }
}
```

Then you can post to the correct controller using

```
// Post to the SomeLogic method of FirstController
<input type="submit" formaction="@Url.Action("SomeLogic", "First")" value="submit" />
// Post to the SomeLogic method of SecondController
<input type="submit" formaction="@Url.Action("SomeLogic", "Second")" value="submit3" />
```

Comment: Will I be able to pass cimplex objects?

Comment: Yes of course (all the name/values pairs of your form controls will be sent to the server method)

Comment: Excellent, I have to ask this question because I've had issues with url.action before, both with complex objects and with query string. I want to keep my url clean of query strings what so ever, so sorry for this up front. I have to make sure this will be as clean as possible.

Comment: Making a POST with a form will not add any query string values (the data is sent in the body of the request), Its only if you use a form with `FormMethod.Get` that adds the name/values pairs of your form controls as query string values

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. It's just the fact that url.action caused me problems before, as it generates an HtmlString, so I have to make sure all the edges are cared for.

Comment: A `HtmlString` is not a issue. I'm not sure what you problem was, but perhaps it's related to [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47401081/actionlink-with-no-routevalues-being-loaded-with-routevalue-breaking-dynamic-pag/47401519#47401519) - i.e. its added the query string values from your GET method that generates the view

Answer (score 1):

Just intercept the submit with jQuery

You can add an ID to your form, to be able to select it easily in jQuery

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("SomeLogic", "Controller1", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "yourForm" })
```

Then

```
$("#yourForm").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var url1 = '@(Url.Action("SomeLogic1", "SomeController", null, Request.Url.Scheme))';
    var url2 = '@(Url.Action("SomeLogic", "SomeController2", null, Request.Url.Scheme))';

    //Whatever logic should you do to select which URL you want to POST to

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url_selected_above,
        data: $('#yourForm').serializeArray(),
        success: function (xhr, response) {
             //...
        },
        error: function (xhr, response) {
            //...
        }
    });
});
```

This should work if all the methods expect the same view model.

Alternatively, if you do not want to mess around in the UI, you can do something as such in the action that generates the form.

```
var controllerName = "SomeController";
var actionName = "Action1";

//do your logic to select whichever controller/action.

viewModel.ControllerName = controllerName;
viewModel.ActionName = actionName;
```

And in the view that has the form:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(@Model.ActionName, @Model.ControllerName, FormMethod.Post)
```

Again, if all the actions expect the same view model, that should work.

Comment: Question is, if it will create any sort of query string, I cannot allow query strings in my url.

Comment: @BarrJ It won't. the 'null' parameter in `Url.Action` will produce an URL without any query parameters.

Comment: This is a good approach, But I'd rather not deal with client side here, As I already use submit from the client using the Mvc Paged List. I am taking control of the <a> tag and using it as submit button for every page. So mixing logics will make things worse.

Comment: @BarrJ I edited the answer with something else you could do server side.